# Assinging value to variable outside class

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am accessing JSON file in ComponentDidMount in class A, i need to access that result outside class and need to use that in Class B

```
let test;
console.log(test);
class CustomerPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(): void {
    $.getJSON("/api/LocaleStrings")
      .done(results => {
        let JsonString = JSON.parse(results);
        test = new LocalizedStrings(JsonString);
      })
     .fail(console.log.bind(console));
  }
}
```

Here, `console.log(test)` yields `undefined`.

Comment: Use state to get your array stored and use it where you want to use

Comment: Can you please show me how i can use that in my code

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading up a bit more on how React components share data. The component that needs the data can have an input defined, in which you can pass the test variable. Or using a redux store (which could potentially be a little too complex for your application). If you really want to continue this route. You can always use the window object to set a global variable: `window.test = 'bla';`. This is available anywhere in the application with `console.log(window.test);`.

You would have to update your code to:
`window.test = new LocalizedStrings(JsonString);`.

Verifying that it is set can be done with an interval:

```
setInterval(function() {
   console.log(window.test);
 }, 100);
```

Comment: Mmm, you changed your code. The variable test only becomes available after the JSON has loaded. If you add `console.log(test)` right after  `test = new LocalizedStrings(JsonString);` it should print it correctly. The questions is more, why do you want to have the 'test' variable available outside the react component?

Comment: I want to use that value in another class.

Comment: I recommend reading up a bit more on how React components share data. The component that needs the data can have an input defined, in which you can pass the `test` variable. Or using a redux store (which is quite complex). If you really want to continue this route. You can always use the window object to pass the variable: `window.test = 'bla' `. This is available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your `console.log(test)` gets executed before the AJAX call returns, and at that point it will be uninitialized (`undefined`). Place your `console.log` inside the `done` function.

You could store your AJAX result in your component's state:

```
class CustomerPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { test: null };
  }
  componentDidMount(): void {
    $.getJSON("/api/LocaleStrings")
      .done(results => {
        let JsonString = JSON.parse(results);
        this.setState({
          test: new LocalizedStrings(JsonString);
        });           
      })
     .fail(console.log.bind(console));
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to use that in another class, so only i am assiging outside class.

Comment: In that case, the answers by @apokryfos is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an "event" that notifies anyone who is interested that `test` is available:

```
interface CustomerPageProps {
   onLocaleStringsLoaded?: (test:object) => void
}

class CustomerPage extends React.Component<CustomerPageProps> {
  static defaultProps {
       onLocaleStringsLoaded: () => {} //nothing by default
  }
  componentDidMount(): void {
    $.getJSON("/api/LocaleStrings")
      .done(results => {
        let JsonString = JSON.parse(results);
        const test = new LocalizedStrings(JsonString);
        this.props.onLocaleStringsLoaded(test);
      }).fail(console.log.bind(console));
  }    
}
```

Then at some point in your code you could have:

```
<CustomerPage onLocaleStringsLoaded={window.console.log.bind(window.console)} />
```

which will print to the console once the result is available.